# Поиск по listView android

Tags: java, android, listview

Есть задача реализовать поиск по listViev, но данный код  адекватно ищет только по первым символам, если ввести символы которые в словах находятся в средине или конце - то он вообще не дает результатов. Если нужно привести дополнительный код - говорите я добавлю.

```
 mInputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // When user changed the Text
            ListFragment.this.mAdapter.getFilter().filter(cs);
        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                      int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
```

ListFragment.java

```
public class ListFragment extends Fragment {

private ListView mListView;
private EditText mInputSearch;

private ArrayList<String> mList;
private ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mList = new ArrayList<String>();
    fillArray();

    mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),R.layout.item_list, mList);

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_list, container, false);

    mInputSearch = (EditText) v.findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);

    mListView = (ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

    return v; }

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    mInputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
            // When user changed the Text
            ListFragment.this.mAdapter.getFilter().filter(cs);


        }

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                                      int arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
}

private void fillArray() {

    mList.add("Lorem");
    mList.add("Ipsum");
    mList.add("Dolor");
    mList.add("Sit");
    mList.add("Amet");
    mList.add("Consectetur");
    mList.add("Adipiscing");
    mList.add("Elit");
    mList.add("Fusce");
    mList.add("Pharetra");
    mList.add("Luctus");
    mList.add("Sodales");

    Collections.sort(mList);
}
}
```

Comment: Видимо дело в реализации фильтра для списка. Приведите его код. Там, видимо, идёт поиск всей переданной строке в списке, тогда как вам, видимо, надо находить совпадения по каждому символу в переданной строке.

Comment: @ЮрийСПб в том то и дело, что нету реализации, это все. Фильтр как будто начинает поиск с начала строки по заданным символам, и при несовпадении - дальше не ищет, а мне нужно что бы он просто проверял наличие заданной комбинации символов  в каждом из элементов массива .

Comment: Значит вам надо написать (скопипастить с гугла и чуть допилить) свою рализацию фильтра.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Для того, чтоб настроить свой фильтр, нужно решить некую последовательность:

1. Создать свой custom адаптер.
2. Привязать к нему интерфейс Filterable
3. Настроить метод getFilter() под себя.

Я сделал рабочий пример, для того чтоб вы могли потестить:

Кастомный адаптер:

```
public class myAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements Filterable {

private List<String> allModelItemsArray;
private List<String> filteredModelItemsArray;
private Activity context;
private ModelFilter filter;
private LayoutInflater inflater;

public myAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<String> list) {
    super(context, R.layout.list_item, list);
    this.context = context;
    this.allModelItemsArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    allModelItemsArray.addAll(list);
    this.filteredModelItemsArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    filteredModelItemsArray.addAll(allModelItemsArray);
    inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    getFilter();
}
@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    if (filter == null){
        filter  = new ModelFilter();
    }
    return filter;
}
static class ViewHolder {
    protected TextView text;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View view = null;
    String m = filteredModelItemsArray.get(position);
    ViewHolder viewHolder = null;
    if (convertView == null) {

        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        viewHolder.text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvItem);
        view.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        view = convertView;
        viewHolder = ((ViewHolder) view.getTag());
    }
    viewHolder.text.setText(m);
    return view;
}

private class ModelFilter extends Filter
{

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

        constraint = constraint.toString().toLowerCase();
        FilterResults result = new FilterResults();
        if(constraint.toString().length() > 0)
        {
            ArrayList<String> filteredItems = new ArrayList<String>();

            for(int i = 0, l = allModelItemsArray.size(); i < l; i++)
            {
                String m = allModelItemsArray.get(i);
                if(m.toLowerCase().contains(constraint))
                    filteredItems.add(m);
            }
            result.count = filteredItems.size();
            result.values = filteredItems;
        }
        else
        {
            synchronized(this)
            {
                result.values = allModelItemsArray;
                result.count = allModelItemsArray.size();
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

        filteredModelItemsArray = (ArrayList<String>)results.values;
        notifyDataSetChanged();
        clear();
        for(int i = 0, l = filteredModelItemsArray.size(); i < l; i++)
            add(filteredModelItemsArray.get(i));
        notifyDataSetInvalidated();
    }
  }
}
```

MainActivity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
ListView lv;
EditText editText;
myAdapter adapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
    editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

    ArrayList<String> values = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 25; i++) {
        values.add("Item:" + i);
    }
    adapter = new myAdapter(this, values);
    lv.setAdapter(adapter);

    editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
        }
        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());
        }
    });
  }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/lv"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

list_item.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvItem"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:textSize="12sp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Спасибо, решил проблему аналогичным образом.