# Событие окончания ввода текста в EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

Пишу приложение для заказа такси, на одной из активити есть EditText и ListVew для поиска адресов из базы, когда пассажир вводит 3 или более символа делаем запрос в базу на совпадение, вопрос такой как можно отловить окончание ввода текста что бы не на каждый ввод текста делать запрос в базу, а например пользователь ввел "мира" идет задержка 2-3 сек если дальше ввода не было делаем запрос в базу.

```
        searchAdressTextInput.getEditText().addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        };

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            filterWithDelay(s.toString());
        }
    });

public void filterWithDelay(final String s) {
    latest = (int) System.currentTimeMillis(); //обновляем время последнего изменения текста
    Handler h = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            if(System.currentTimeMillis() - delay > latest) //если в последние 2 секунды текст не менялся
                Log.d("HELLO", s);
        }
    };
    h.postDelayed(r, delay + 50);//в главный поток с задержкой delay + 50 миллисекунд
}
```

Comment: подскажите язык, стек технологий. Я знаю два способа, но один хорош для котлин, другой требует RxJava. Способ Котлин можно и на java переделать, но код, скорее всего, некрасивый будет.

Comment: За основу можете взять [этот ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/481497/177345)

Comment: @pavlofff Вы отсылаете к замечательному ответу, но он никак не помогает решить проблему автора, изменения `editText` автором вопроса, как я понял, уже отслеживаются ровно тем же образом.

Comment: @Alex_Skvortsov java

Comment: System.currentTimeMillis(); может возвращать значение, которое не помещается в int! Используйте Long!

Comment: Добавил пояснение на счет типов)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На Java при условии отсутствия Rx я бы решал примерно так. Код писался на коленке и без компиляции, возможны синтаксические неточности.

```
Long latest = 0;
Long delay = 2000; //2 секунды

public void filterWithDelay(String s){ //функция, запускающая запрос в БД через 2 секунды
    latest = System.currentTimeMillis(); //обновляем время последнего изменения текста
    Handler h = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());
    Runnable r = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if(System.currentTimeMillis() - delay > latest) //если в последние 2 секунды текст не менялся
                        simpleFilter(s); //сделать запрос в БД
                }
           };
    h.postDelayed(r, delay + 50);//в главный поток с задержкой delay + 50 миллисекунд
}
```

**Update:**

Пусть у нас есть в активности / фрагменте переменная `EditText` c именем `editText` и она уже инициализирована. Тогда вызов `filterWithDelay` осуществляем так:

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {}
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {}
    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        filterWithDelay(s.toString())
    }
});
```

**Update 2:**

**Почему важно объявить переменные именно типом `Long`?**

Дело в том, что тип `int` ограничен в языке Java значением 4 294 967 296, если попытаться бОльшее число - Вы получите отрицательное число с другим значением. Этот эффект называется переполнение. Тип `Long` в свою очередь может хранить числа до 100 000 000 000 000 000 000 (примерно). Метод `System.currentTimeMillis()` возвращает количество миллисекунд, прошедших с определенной даты (если не ошибаюсь, отсчет с 1970 года). Это количество намного больше, чем может вместить `int`.

Comment: не получилось, simpleFilter(s); заменил на вывод в лог, сообщения вылетают просто с задержкой при вводе каждого символа

Comment: @Goodluck даже если вводить символы быстро?

Comment: @Goodluck обновил ответ, добавив указание, как получать изменения в тексте. Создал проект и проверил свой код - все работает.

Comment: да делаю всё тоже самое вывожу в лог, начинаю писать например Hello в логах выходит H He Hel Hell Hello с задержкой в 2 сек

Comment: @Goodluck можете полный код класса в вопрос добавить / просто куда-то залить, чтобы я посмотрел в текущем виде?

Comment: добавил код без куска обращения к базе (он тут без нужды)

Comment: @Goodluck а можно с объявлением `latest ` и `delay` пожалуйста? Но вообще странно, вроде все должно работать

Comment: Блин я нашел свою ошибку я эти переменные объявил как int а не long и всё заработало, только не понятно почему именно long а не int